# How to avoid warning SQL0347W The recursive common table expression "table" may contain an infinite loop

Tags: sql, recursion, warnings, common-table-expression, db2-luw

I have tried to avoid the warning on a CTE query, I add the use of a counter, and this works but only when the query uses one "union all" if I add another " union all" on the query the message returns, any idea of why isn't using the second counter?

this is the query:

```
 with impl (qry, n) AS ( SELECT 'Qry1_EC_Ai'  , 0
  FROM 
     table a 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Qry2_Imp_Opt', n + 3
  FROM 
    impl prev 
  WHERE 
 n < 2 
 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Qry3_Imp_Opt', n + 5
  FROM 
    impl prev
  WHERE 
 n < 3
 )
select 
  imp.n ,
  imp.qry
from 
  impl imp
```

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a CTE rather than just 3 UNION ALL queries against table A?

Comment: This is just a simplified version of the original query,   just to replicate the behavior, in the original query  we are using 6 unions all  to get the expected result, and the query works as expected, but we can't avoid the warning

Comment: What's the client interface you use? JDBC, CLI/ODBC?

Comment: If CLI/ODBC, then look at the [IgnoreWarnList CLI/ODBC configuration keyword](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=keywords-ignorewarnlist). There is no JDBC equivalent setting / property.